# Retrofit throws an error

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I've created some Pojo model and I'm getting data from api into my android app. Data should be downloaded on button click.

Here is how I made this:

```
public class DownloadMain extends Fragment implements Callback<Partner> {

    private static final String TAG = DownloadMain.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button dloadPartners;
    private Call callPartners;

    public DownloadMain() {}

    public DownloadMain newInstance() { return new DownloadMain(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_main, container, false);

        dloadPartners = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPartners);
        dloadPartners.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

        callPartners = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callPartners.enqueue(DownloadMain.this);
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

        if(response.body() == null) {
            try {
                response.errorBody().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Partners!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            List<Partner> partners = (List<Partner>) response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of partners received: " + partners.size());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

So problem is here. When I click on button it gives me a notice (toast) "No partners!". 
And when I click again it throws me an error:

> IllegalStateException: Already executed. at
>   retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:78)

at this line in Button onClick method:

```
callPartners.enqueue(DownloadMain.this);
```

I can't figure it out why retrofit is not getting any data.

**QUESTION: Could someone help me to resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

You can call only once. If you need to do more calls use clone.
From [javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html):

> An invocation of a Retrofit method that sends a request to a webserver and returns a response. Each call yields its own HTTP request and response pair. **Use clone() to make multiple calls with the same parameters to the same webserver**; this may be used to implement polling or to retry a failed call.

Basically the code should be

```
callPartners.clone().enqueue(DownloadMain.this);
```

Comment: This resolved one part of problem. Still I can't get any partners from api